# How can I remove this border style using MUI sx inline

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Looking to remove this border prop in the image using inline sx prop from mui.[image]

Its a textfield if thats important..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this sx prop inside your **TextField**

```
sx={{
      "& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
             border: "0 none",
           },
    }}
```

that's how you can find it

[image]

Comment: Thanks, It worked, and I'm just trying to understand where you got the notched outline so that I can understand this for the future. Could you please explain?

Comment: its in the generated fieldset by MUI, you can find it when you look in the inspect panel

Comment: i uploaded image in answer for explanation